# Excel 2010 SUMPRODUCT with multiple conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have three columns `A`=Date, `B`=Region, `C`=Qty. I need to identify the `Qty` in the `GR` region between two dates.

I have tried this formula with no success:

```
$B$3=Beginning date,
$C$3=Ending date

=SUMPRODUCT(($A$6:$A$5000>=$B$3) * ($A$6:$A$5000 < $C$3) * ($B$6:$B$5000="GR"),$C$6:$C$5000)
```

Output is 0.

Comment: Did you get this to work? It worked for me.